# How to color a mesh partially in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

In the project I'm working on we need to show available office spaces in the building and the idea is to highlight just a portion of the floor rather than entire floor. For instance, if the space is located at the corner, so only corner will needs to be highlighted not the entire floor. The red strip is a mesh on top of each floor. I'm looking for ways to highlight just a part of it. Hitting my head against the wall to figure out how... please help! Thanks a lot

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cldvs.png)

Comment: You can use [vertex coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330342/threejs-assign-different-colors-to-each-vertex-in-a-geometry) or break the mesh into pieces.

Comment: The problem is with the vertex coloring that I don't know how many faces will have one or another mesh since the model creation is not under my control. How can I break the mesh into pieces though? Thx

Comment: I meant break the mesh into pieces in your 3D modeling program. For vertex coloring you'd need to just walk through the vertices to find the ones whose position is near where you clicked. If you don't have vertices located at the right places and you can't edit the mesh then the only thing I can think of is to switch out the mesh's texture depending on where it's clicked.

Comment: Yes, it is requires some additional changes on the models, which I don't really have access to. But thanks for an idea anyways!