# three.js assigning different colors (gradients) to each vertex in a geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to modify the following lines of code so when the button is clicked the neighborhood vertex **of the selected mesh** gets colored in a gradient effect.

```
function addSphere()
{
var position = new Array();
var notAboveGround = true;
while(notAboveGround){
    position[0]=Math.random()*floorSide-floorSide/2;
    position[1]=Math.random()*floorSide-floorSide/2;
    position[2]=Math.random()*floorSide/5;
    var sphereSide = Math.random()*floorSide/12+floorSide/50;
    //alert("cubeSide="+cubeSide);
    if(position[2]-sphereSide>0){
        notAboveGround = false;
    }
}

var faceColorMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( 
{ color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,shading:THREE.FlatShading,polygonOffset: true,polygonOffsetUnits: 1,polygonOffsetFactor: 1} );

// var sphereGeom= new THREE.SphereGeometry(sphereSide,0);
var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(80,10,10);
for ( var i = 0; i < sphereGeom.faces.length; i++ ) 
{
    face = sphereGeom.faces[ i ];   
    face.color= baseColor;      
}
var sphere= new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom, faceColorMaterial );
sphere.position.set(0, 150, 0);
// creates a wireMesh object
wireSphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x116611, wireframe: true }));

scene.add(sphere);
// wireMesh object is added to the original as a sub-object
sphere.add(wireSphere );

targetList.push(sphere);
```

}

I am trying to use the code samples by Mr. Stemkoski from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330342/threejs-assign-different-colors-to-each-vertex-in-a-geometry) :

```
// this material causes a mesh to use colors assigned to vertices
var vertexColorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

var color, point, face, numberOfSides, vertexIndex;

// faces are indexed using characters
var faceIndices = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];

var size = 100;
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( size, size, size );

// first, assign colors to vertices as desired
for ( var i = 0; i < cubeGeometry.vertices.length; i++ ) 
{
    point = cubeGeometry.vertices[ i ];
    color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
    color.setRGB( 0.5 + point.x / size, 0.5 + point.y / size, 0.5 + point.z / size );
    cubeGeometry.colors[i] = color; // use this array for convenience
}

// copy the colors to corresponding positions 
//     in each face's vertexColors array.
for ( var i = 0; i < cubeGeometry.faces.length; i++ ) 
{
    face = cubeGeometry.faces[ i ];
    numberOfSides = ( face instanceof THREE.Face3 ) ? 3 : 4;
    for( var j = 0; j < numberOfSides; j++ ) 
    {
        vertexIndex = face[ faceIndices[ j ] ];
        face.vertexColors[ j ] = cubeGeometry.colors[ vertexIndex ];
    }
}

cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, vertexColorMaterial );
```

However, I am struggling with the javascript closer property and not sure how to start from here. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add color to the vertex you have to set [the vertexColors array](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Face3.js#L16) in the face.
In the example code you pasted it is also done like that but you miss this piece of code inside your own example. So you should add:

```
var numberOfSides, j, vertexIndex;

for ( var i = 0; i < sphereGeom.faces.length; i++ ) 
{
    face = sphereGeom.faces[ i ];   
    face.color= baseColor;      
    numberOfSides = ( face instanceof THREE.Face3 ) ? 3 : 4;
    for( j = 0; j < numberOfSides; j++ ) 
    {
        vertexIndex = face[ faceIndices[ j ] ];
        face.vertexColors[ j ] = sphereGeom.colors[ vertexIndex ];
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way, how can I set selectedFace[0] as a pivot of the gradient effect?

Comment: cubeGeometry.faces.length ->does it indicate how many neighboring meshes are there?