# cannot change material color using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, webgl

I have a `obj` file which contains vertex groups along with the main object. I am trying to assign color to each of the groups tagged through vertex group. What I could find is that in `three.js` each vertex group is of type `Object3D` and there is no function like `setColor`, instead each such children has two children of the type `THREE.Mesh` and it has `setColor` function accessed through a material property.  I am not clear about this hierarchy. How do I set color to each vertex group.

One more thing earlier version of `three.js` had different hierarchy of object children relationship. please provide me some input. I am profoundly looking for a solution

Answer (score 2):

There are several similar questions on stack**overflow** that can help you like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28471675/1697459) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10330342/1697459).

To be able set colors to vertexes you need to walk the object tree till you find the faces of the mesh geometry and there you can assign a `vertexColors` array:

```
var numberOfSides, j, vertexIndex;

for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++ ) 
{
    face = geometry.faces[ i ];   
    face.color = baseColor;      
    numberOfSides = ( face instanceof THREE.Face3 ) ? 3 : 4;
    for( j = 0; j < numberOfSides; j++ ) 
    {
        vertexIndex = face[ faceIndices[ j ] ];
        face.vertexColors[ j ] = geometry.colors[ vertexIndex ];
    }
}
```

For more details check the linked questions.