# Can't color the vertices but if use faces the three.js works

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to put some color on vertices but the colors do not appear. I am using Three.js library.
This is the function example I am using:

```
function parserExpose(arr) {
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60, 60, arr.x - 1, arr.y - 1);

    for (var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i++) {
        geometry.vertices[i].z = (arr.topo[i].topoValues / 65535 * 2470);
        geometry.vertices[i].color = new THREE.Color(Math.random() * 0x00ffff);
    }
    geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    geometry.needsUpdate = true;
    geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;
    geometry.__dirtyNormals = true;
    geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    //vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
    //THREE.FaceColors 
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 3}));

    scene.add(plane);

}
```

If I use `geometry.faces[]` I can change the color but I only want to change on vertices not the faces.

Thx in advance. :)

Comment: Vertices don't have anything to color, they don't have any meshes associated with them.

Comment: @Brennam How can i get the faces that are associated with vertice? exist one way to do that? :/

Comment: You can't. Vertices are infinitely small representations of a point. If you want to color them, add a geometry/mesh at the same location and associate to the vertex.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? It sounds like you want a particle system or point cloud

Comment: @2pha For now i only want to color the vertices. i was able to do that with this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330342/threejs-assign-different-colors-to-each-vertex-in-a-geometry). 
But the next achive will be to do some point cloud. You have some examples of that? :)

Comment: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_raycasting_pointcloud